# How to expose forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase cmp to be able to select it in theme setup

Tags: community, aura, navigation, experience-cloud

I have implemented a custom navigation aura component.

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase">
    <aura:attribute name="navigationLinkSetId" type="String" default="Default_Navigation"/>
    <aura:attribute name="addHomeMenuItem" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav slds-list_horizontal" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.menuItems}" var="item">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!item.subMenu}">
                    <li class="{!item.active ? 'slds-is-active' : ''}">
                        <a href="" data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" style="font-size: 13px"
                           class="slds-navigation-list_vertical__action slds-text-link_reset">
                            {!item.label}<span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!item.subMenu}" var="subItem">
                                <li><a data-menu-item-id="{!subItem.id}" href="">{!subItem.label}</a></li>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <li class="{!item.active ? 'slds-is-active' : ''}">
                            <a href="" data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" style="font-size: 13px"
                               class="slds-navigation-list_vertical__action slds-text-link_reset">
                                {!item.label}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

But I could not find a way how to set this component in the theme setup page. Currently, I embedded the component directly inside a custom theme template, but better would be to be able to select it from this menu.

[image]

Currently we have exposed a checkbox 'Use Custom Navigation' to specify this single custom navigation component.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.useCustomNavigation}">
    <div class="slds-col_bump-left slds-align-bottom navigation-pc">
        <c:defaultCustomNavigation navigationLinkSetId="{!v.customNavigationMenu}"/>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{! !v.useCustomNavigation}">
    <div>
        {!v.navBar}
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bubble up the design attributes to the theme assuming that you are able to edit it. Going this route allows you to pass the value down as you're intending. I should note that this approach requires users to enter the ID or developer name of the navigation menu in order for it to work. When creating custom design attributes, Salesforce does not provide a drop down menu of navigation menus that you can pick from.

Abbreviated example below. A larger example can be found at https://github.com/GSA/uswds-sf-lightning-community

```
<!-- theme.cmp -->
<aura:component
  implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout"
  extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase"
  access="global"
>
<aura:attribute
  name="secondaryNavigationLinkSetId"
  type="String"
  default=""
/>
<div>
<c:customNavComponent 
  navigationLinkSetId="{!v.secondaryNavigationLinkSetId}"
/>


<!-- theme.design -->
<design:component label="USWDS Theme Layout">
  <design:attribute
    name="secondaryNavigationLinkSetId"
    label="Header Secondary Nav Menu Name"
    description="Allows you to add links below the search box such as 'advanced search' or others that may be relevant"
  />
</design:component>
```

Comment: This is something different. I've already implemented the definition of custom navigation menu. Now I seek a way to define which custom component should be used as the navigation component. In the picklist there are 2 standard one, and I've created a custom one. For now, I've just exposed a checkbox 'Use Custom Navigation'.